# Understanding Piping in AWK

Tags: awk

I found this example in a lecture by Brian Kernighan. 
to add together the prices of food items in a two column table

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{amount[$1] += $2}

END {for (name in amount)
           print name, amount[name] | "sort -k1 "
     print "Finished processing everything!"
        }
```

The last print statement `print "Finished...."` is my own little addition.

For the input

```
pizza 200
beer 100
pizza 500
beer 50
```

it produces the output

```
Finished processing everything!
beer 150
pizza 700
```

i.e. it adds up the prices of beer, and pizza entries together. What I don't get is how the last print statement that I added was executed before the for loop.

Also why is the `| sort...` statement inside the `for` loop? Shouldn't it be after the for loop after all the printing has been done, sort of like how one would do the same thing at the bash command line via 
`cat file | sort`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AWK(1P)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) has a section about `Output Statements`

In `awk` piping creates a stream which remains open until you close it. This allows it to be used in-loop. Using your example:

```
{amount[$1] += $2}
END {
    for (name in amount)
        print name, amount[name] | "sort -k1"
    close("sort -k1")
    print "Finished processing everything!"
}
```

This closes `sort -k1`, allowing it to be printed.